# angularjs - ngview part doesn't work after referring to a specific controller in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

The ng-view part in index.html was working well before... it stopped working after i added another controller function to the angular module. it does work again only if i remove the script that i used to refer the above mentioned controller to index.html, which give me the feeling that there can be a issue in that controller where amateur me can not identify...any insight from anyone is highly praised.....(pardon me if i have done any stupid mistakes since im new to both angularjs and stackoverflow)

below is my index.html.............

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="fishingbot">
        <head>
 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


            <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
            <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-app/app.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-app/bot-list/bot-list-controller.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-app/bot-display/bot-display-controller.js"></script>
            <script src="angular-app/bot-data-factory/bot-data-factory.js"></script>
            <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
            
            <script src="bower_components/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/fusioncharts-angular/angular-fusioncharts.js"></script>

            **// this is the script that refers to above-said controller.....**            
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            <script src="/webapp/chart-data-controller.js"></script>
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            
            <title>Automated Fishing Bot</title>
        </head>     
        <body>
          
                
**//ng-view part...this loads a table from another html page.....**
                <div class="content-wrapper" ng-view >
                     
                </div>
**//this is html part which gets the functionality from controller**
                <div ng-controller="chartController">
                    <fusioncharts width="450" 
                                  height="230" 
                                  type="bar2d" 
                                  id="chart-1" 
                                  dataformat="json" 
                                  datasource={{data}}>
                    </fusioncharts>
                </div>
             </html>
```

the controller which gives the pain........

```js
angular.module('fishingbot', ['ng-fusioncharts']).controller('chartController',chartController);

function chartController($scope, $http){
    var getdata;enter code here
    console.log('Check 2');
    getData = function(url, callback) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(callback);
    };

    getData('/api/bots', function(response) {
        console.log('Check 3');
        console.log(response);
        var datasource,
            doc,
            data = [],
            linkeddata = [],
            chart;

        chart = {
            caption: "Total Triggers",
            showValues: 0,
            theme: "zune"
        };
        console.log(response.data.length);
        console.log('Check 4');
        for (var _i = 0; _i < response.data.length; _i++) {
            doc = response.data[_i];
            data.push({
                label: doc.BotID,
                value: doc.ActiveHours,
                link: 'newchart-json-' + _i.toString()
            });
            console.log('Check 5');
            linkeddata.push({
                id: _i.toString(),
                linkedchart: {
                    chart: {
                        caption: 'Triggers of a Fishing bot  - '+ doc.BotID,
                        showValues: 0,
                        theme: "carbon"
                    },
                    data: doc.TriggerData.map(function(ele) {
                        return {
                            label: ele.TimeStamp,
                            value: ele.Triggers
                        };
                    })
                }
            });
```

the function in the controller works well too...

the index2.html which supposed to load through the ng-view in index.html and indeed which does load if the above-mentioned controller is removed........

```html
<body>
    <h1>THIS IS THROUGH NG-VIEW</h1>
</body>
```

**SOLVED**

*The problem seems to be was that we can not add multiple dependencies to the angular module from different scripts(though i have no idea how things work)...thus removed the 'ng-fusioncharts' dependency from chartController and put it in a another script where 'ngRoutes' dependency is configured. then on things started to work as they suppose be...*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A couple notable things I would suggest are 1) format your code. 2) Strip your code down to the bare minimum it requires to reproduce your issue. Questions simply seeking debugging help are not on-topic here and will be closed.

Comment: thanks for the insight and sure i'll keep them in mind for future reference:)